# why Ejs not being recognized by vscode

Tags: javascript, html, ejs

I have searching for solutions but nothing working. I installed **ejs** extention on vs code and also dependency. added ***ejs and html** in setting and tried several solution on StackOverFlow. The answer should come as **Its a Weekend or Weekday** but <%KindOfDay%> EJS not working.

/view/list.ejs code is:

```
<body>
    <h1>Its a <%KindOfDay%> </h1>
</body>
```

and app.js code is:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");


const app = express();

app.set('views', path(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');


app.get("/", (req, res) => {

    var today = new Date();
    var currentDate = today.getDate();
    var day = "";

    if (currentDate == 6 || currentDate == 0) {
        day = "Weekend";
    } else {
        day = "Weekday";
    }

    res.render("list", { KindOfDay: day });
console.log(day);
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Server Running");
})
```

I am providing screenshots and marked in red.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hSaR.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkxRY.png)

Comment: you need to print the value, `<%=` instead, its not a vs code issue

Comment: <%= KindOfDay %>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are wrong tag to display an output. To display output write like this

```js
<%= KindOfDay %>
```

The one you are using is `'Scriptlet' tag, for control-flow, no output`. It is used with loops and if else statements etc.

Comment: Thank you so much. it worked!!! I have been searching for solution more than 12 hours. you saved me. :)

Comment: Sure. I will...